# Как вернуть строку с null-terminated символом в середине из delphi dll в c#?

Tags: c#, delphi

delphi:

```
function Test(): PChar; stdcall;
var
  LocalStr: String;
begin
  LocalStr:= 'Test string with'+ #0 + 'null-terminated in body';
  Result:= CoTaskMemAlloc(SizeOf(Char) * Length(LocalStr) + 1);
  StrLCopy(Result, PChar(LocalStr), Length(LocalStr));
end;
```

c#:

```
[DllImport(@"путь к dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern string Test();
```

Возвращается только "Test string with". Оно и понятно, так как тип возврата PChar. А вот как вернуть целиком такую строку, я не знаю.

Comment: А как вы это делаете для остальных строк?

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну, функция `StrLCopy` копирует `PChar`, то есть до первого `#0`.

Comment: Это всё понятно, только как сделать, что бы получить нужный эффект? Если можно пример.

Comment: Правильно строку формировать так:

    Result:= CoTaskMemAlloc(SizeOf(Char) * Length(LocalStr) + SizeOf(Char));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё оказалось очень интересно. Это особенность среды delphi:

```
function Test(Text: WideString): WideString; stdcall;
var
  LocalStr: String;
begin
  LocalStr:= 'Test string with'+ #0 + 'null-terminated in body';
  Result := localStr;
end;
```

И теперь самое интересное (обратите внимание что первым аргументом должен идти out парамтр)
c#:

```
[DllImport(@"путь к dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void Test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string Result, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string text);
```